# The purpose of ai_next and ai_addr inside the addrinfo struct

Tags: c, sockets, struct

I am teaching myself socket programming and I've recently come across `getaddrinfo` and the `addrinfo` struct. From my understanding, the majority of the files in the struct are ints that you can use by specifying macros, for example, if I wanted to `AF_INET` in my `addrinfo` struct, I would specify either `AF_INET`, or the integer 2 (I don't know this for sure, what header file is it declared in?).
Well, I don't think I quite understand why there is an sockaddr and pointer to another addrinfo. I've been told that the latter creates a linked list, but what is the purpose behind it?

Comment: `struct addrinfo` serves two case: 1st case: Passing hints to `getaddrinfo()` on what the caller is interested. If having the need to pass more then one selection criteria this could be done by addng nodes to the list using the `next`-member. 2nd case: Decribing the result returned by `getaddrinfo()`. The result could be more then one IP-address, if so the `next`-member is used to link to the next result (as already discribed in *Kyle Lemon*'s answer below). However reading the friendly manual would surely also help getting enlighted.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on `AF_INET` having the value of `2`, because the standard doesn't require a specific value. The only requirement is that `AF_INET`, `AF_INET6`, `AF_UNIX`, and `AF_UNSPEC` all have distinct values. See [`getaddrinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html) and [`sys/socket.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html). (Not to mention, the only possible justification for using the value of a standards-provided symbolic constant instead of the symbolic constant itself is spelled _http://IOCCC.ORG/_.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend always specifying the values using the type names.  They may be different on different systems.

The [getaddrinfo(3) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) describes the fields of the `addrinfo` struct, but to summarize the way the linked list works, consider this code:

```
for (struct addrinfo *ai = ...; ai != NULL; ai = ai->ai_next) {
  printf("address: %s -> %s\n", ai->ai_canonname,
         inet_ntop(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_addr, buf, buflen));
}
```

The `addrinfo*` you get back from `getaddrinfo` may point to another one, which may point to another, and so on.  This is how it represents an address which can resolve to multiple different IPs (for load balancing, dual-stack IPv4/IPv6, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your response, better understanding now. However, I have a slightly off-topic question. You use an ellipsis in your for loop. I know that means that there can be a varying number of variables, but, I don't 100% understand it when used inside a for loop.

Comment: That's my way of saying "code is missing here".  In particular you need to call `getaddrinfo` and check the return value/errno before using it in the for loop.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, the main question is - "what is the reason behind it?". The reason is, one host could've multiple internet address assigned to it. For ex, if you run "host www.google.com" command this will give you multiple internet address, so the point of linked list of multiple addrinfo is to keep all the returned internet addresses, thus allowing you to properly translate network address and service.

When you write an app and trying to connect to a public server that might have multiple internet address, these linked list of address will give you the flexibility of making a connection to an appropriate interface.

Comment: So, these multiple IP address point to the same website, but what are they exactly? Mirrors?

Comment: Could be. Depends on how the infrastructure was implemented. It's norm for service like google to have multiple internet addresses.